# Android Application did not close cursor or database

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

Im running into an issue inserting items into my database. It really odd that the program will run through 4 rows and insert them fine, but on the 5th row it crashes and I got three reports of Application did not close cursor or database. In my code I am closing and reopening both the cursor and the database so I am really confused on how this is happening. Here is the code.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_NEW:
            if (resultCode == -1) {
                Integer chapterId = data.getIntExtra("chapterId", -1);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Selected Chapter: " + chapterId.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                if (chapterId != -1) {
                    DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
                    for (int i = 0; i < questions.getTitle().size(); i++) {
                        db.insertQuestion(chapterId.toString(), questions.getTitle().get(i), questions.getAnswer().get(i), questions.getAr().get(i));
                    }
                }
                toast.show();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Thats calling the database to be created through a dbhelper class. Here is the database helper

```
public void insertQuestion(String cat_id, String title, String answer, String article) {
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + QUESTION_TABLE_NAME + " (title,answer,article,picture) VALUES ('" + title + "','" + answer + "','" + article + "','none')"); 
    String id = getQuestionId(title);
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO " + REL_TABLE_NAME + " (question_id, cat_id) VALUES (" + id + "," + cat_id + ")");

}
public String getQuestionId(String title) {
    String id;
    cursor = this.db.rawQuery("SELECT question_id FROM " + QUESTION_TABLE_NAME + " WHERE title = '" + title + "' LIMIT 1", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    id = cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return id;
}
```

I put the cursor at the class level so I can try to manage it better, but still to no avail. Its still crashing after 4 queries.

Comment: you dont get an error from closing your DB in getQuestionId...? it seems like db.close should be called from the termination of your for loop, not within getQuestionId().

Comment: Post the logcat output that shows the crash: there will be a root cause of the crash that indicates what is wrong.

Comment: I think I figured out the problem when looking at the query that is ran. There are ' s in there for plural words and whatnot. Is there a quick way to escape those like in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Try this "fix":

```
DbHelper db = new DbHelper(this);
try{
                    for (int i = 0; i < questions.getTitle().size(); i++) {
                        db.insertQuestion(chapterId.toString(), questions.getTitle().get(i), questions.getAnswer().get(i), questions.getAr().get(i));
                    }
}catch(Exception e1){
   android.util.Log.v("DbHelper Error","Crash: "+e1.getMessage(), e1);
}finally{
db.close();
}
```

Comment: The problem was there was a ' in the string I was trying to insert. Is there a way to escape that and then put it back when I read from the database again? I know in html I could just use the html equivelant, but what about for SQLite and Java?

Comment: Yeah, use the ContentValues class to do the insertion: see http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html#todo_database for an example. This correctly does escaping and everything.